# Handling resources across local vs sandboxed maven test environments

Tags: maven

The standard maven directory structure includes `resources` as follows:

```
  src/main/resources
  src/test/resources
```

When a maven build is initiated on a sandboxed environment - e.g. `jenkins` then all of the artifacts in those directories become available at the sandboxed "current" directory - and without resorting to any paths - either relative or absolute.

But when running `mvn test` *locally* the sandboxed environment is not in play: instead it is just the root directory of the project. In this case those resources would seem to need to be accessed via `src/main[test]/resources`.

Specifically: in a `sandboxed` environment all of the classes to be run are unpacked into a temporary directory *along with the resources under src/[test|main]/resources`*.  Therefore: the files/artifacts under`src/[test|main]/resources` are present in the *current* directory. The "relative" path to those resources is thus

```
    ./
```

But in the `local` environment - e.g. running `mvn test` at the root directory of a local `git` clone - then the *current* directory is the git repo root dir. The "relative" path to the artifacts is thus

```
./src/[test|main]/resources
```

While I realize the artifacts can *also* be accessed via `classLoader.getResourceAsStream` I have apis' that require `File` access.  We use api's like `listFiles()` and there is also the need to generate files in the given directories using `file://` uri as well as literal paths. so we do need file paths.

What can be done here to normalize the paths across these different use cases/environments?

Comment: to be honest I don't understand you question related to sandboxed environments and artifacts becoming available? Do you have an example project?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have updated the question with further details.

Comment: Are you talking about the classpath which makes artifacts/resources accessible during the running of the unit tests?